# How to Install Older iOS Simulators in XCode 4.2.1 (SDK5.0)

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator, addition

I have just bought a new iMac. I then downloaded the latest SDK 5.0 and installed XCode 4.2.1. Everything is working fine. Though I realized that there are only iPhone and iPad Simulators 5.0 available for debugging. So I went on clicking the  More Simulators... I click Install for all items and a while passed, and when I came back, it indicated as "Installed". But when I go back to my XCode, there are still just Simulators 5.0 in the list.

So, how do I go about installing the older simulators in XCode 4.2.1? Did I miss any steps? Or do I need to install older SDKs? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please check <xcode 4.2 parent directory>/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs directory for the simulator if you find them there then they are one the machine.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**X-Code 4.2 will have iOS 5 simulator and library only.** If you want lower version simulator and library with X-Code just goto **X-Code->Prefrences-> Downloads** Tab. In downloads tab you'll have two tabs:

**1) Components** - Here you will have option to download iOS 4.3 simulator(~600 Mb), iOS 4.0-4.1(~670 MB) Device debugging support, iOS 3.0-3.2.2(686.3 MB) Device debugging support.

**2) Documentation**- Yoy will have option to download iOS 5.0,XCode 4.2 Developer libaray,Mac OSX 10.7 Core Library.

[image]

Install the components which ever you need and there you go..Have you installed components this way??

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Ok I think I get what you mean. I just installed both of the debuggin support only, and not the iOS4.3 Simulator. I just installed it and now it works. Thanks

Comment: hi, do you know where these files will be installed, so i can distribute these files to other developers instead of downloading them each time?

Comment: @LolaRun : Well thats something I do not know.. Most probably you have to download those components..

Comment: just like ravin indicated. you can find them at 
"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk"
so you download them once, and copy paste this directory to other computers, it worked for me.

Comment: i just copied iPhoneSImulator4.0.dsk and 4.2, 4.1 3.2  from xcode 4.0 platforms/iphonesimulator.platform/developer/sdks.
and they worked ! :)

Comment: Why isn't 4.2 in the Components list and do you know where can I get it?  I only need the simulator.

Comment: @LolaRun - I just copied all of them to the folder. I am using Xcode 4.2.1 on Lion. But its still not showing up on the schemes. Do I need to install these? If so, how can I do that? Or do I need to make customized schemes or something?

Comment: Ok ... I had to restart the xcode for me to see the Simulator. But now when I try to run it, I am getting alert saying "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled." and another box saying "The simulated application quit. ... Click Relaunch to try again."

Comment: i didn't face such a problem, did you have XCode 4.0 installed on your machine previously? I had previously installed other XCodes at different installation directory, so i went to XCode4.0.2 installation directory, and then "Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs" i copied all sdks into the same path, but inside the XCode4.2.1 directory, (it is usually /Developer).

Answer (score 14):

If Xcode doesn't show the wanted simulators you'll be able to download older xcodes from here:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

For example:

- iOS 5 Simulator -> Xcode 4.3
- iOS 5.1 Simulator -> Xcode 4.3.3
- iOS 6 Simulator -> Xcode 4.6
- iOS 6.1 Simulator -> Xcode 4.6.3
- iOS 7 Simulator -> Xcode 5
- iOS 7.1 Simulator -> Xcode 5.1

You can find the Xcode application inside the downloaded .dmg

1. Open this DMG
2. Right click on the Xcode application and click 'Show Package Contents'
3. Navigate to: Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
4. Copy the found simulator folder (eg. iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk folder)
5. Repeat steps 2 & 3 for your current Xcode application
6. Paste the simulator folder

Restarting Xcode will show you the new added simulators

Happy building & testing!

**Update:**
Tested in xCode 6, working there as well

Comment: Can't get this to work in Xcode 6.1. I want to add iOS 8.0 Simulator to Xcode 6.1. I've moved it over from the DMG (all 2+ GB) yet when I open iOS Simulator the only devices that I can choose from are 8.1 and 7.1 (I installed that one). 8.0 doesn't show up as an option.

Comment: The iOS 8.0 simulator is not supported any more as of the release of Xcode 6.1. If you really want it, you can either install Xcode 6.0 or you can try copying the iPhoenSimulator8.0.sdk and iOS 8.0.simruntime from Xcode 6.0 into Xcode 6.1, but as stated, this is not supported.

Comment: with your solution  i can't get simulator ios 7 on xcode 7 :(