# How to install ios4.0 simulator in xcode4.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, ios-simulator

I found in xcode4.2, there is only ios5.0 & 4.3 simulator exist. My product should support ios4.0+. How can I install the ios4.0 simulator?

Thank you.

[image: XCode4.2 download simulator page]

Comment: Check here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529572/how-to-install-older-ios-simulators-in-xcode-4-2-1-sdk5-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download
http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_4__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_iphone_sdk_4__final.dmg
and install the packages you want on your Developer folder.

Here's step by step on how to do it on Xcode 3.5 but it shouldn't change much from Xcode 4
http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

Comment: Be aware that all tough you can install the iOS 4 simulator if you are targeting iOS 6 you have to remove support for the ARMv6 architecture which means that you will have to set the minimum deployment target to 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, You can't. There is not support.

Also the simulator does not replace real device testing. If something work in the simulator does not mean it work on a device.

My advice, get a device with iOS 4.0 and use that for debuging/testing the app for iOS 4.0.