# Xcode 6.1 does not have iOS 7.0 simulator option

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone have this issue?  I'm able to download and run the 7.1 simulator but I do not see the option to download 7.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "download and run the 7.1 simulator"?

Comment: @NewEngland He meant like this: iOS Simulator > Hardware > Device > Manage Devices - http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLXce.png Unfortunately, I've not seen iOS Simulator 7.0 in Xcode 6+.

Comment: Just another comment - I tried [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032635/3527656) to download old simulators. Unfortunately, I did not find 7.0 simulator option. You can get iOS 6.1 if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you figured this out already on your own but in case you still haven't here goes.

1)  Click Xcode on the top left-hand side of screen.

2) Click on Preferences

3) Click Downloads

4) Under components click the simulator you wish to install. It takes a few minutes though.