# Cocoapods platform version overrides Xcode development target?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I updated my app on the App Store with Xcode development target iOS7.0 recently.

However, one iOS7 user says he cannot open the app after he updated to the latest version.

With the latest version of this app, I changed the cocoapods platform version from iOS7.0 to iOS8.0 so I can install a library which supports over iOS8.

I wonder if I change the platform :ios to IOS7 on cocoapods, he can open the app?

*I don't have iOS7 device now, so I cannot test it on my side yet..
My app name is ListTimer.

Comment: so you have set pods platform version to 8.0 or make it only ios ? according to my understanding it will be good if both pods and app base version are same so it will be '7.0' in your case

Answer (score 0):

According to slide 13 of [introduction to  cocoapods](https://www.slideshare.net/jeffreysambells/intorduction-to-cocoapods?from_m_app=ios) by jeffrey sambells. The syntax of`platform :ios` should be minimum support iOS version of your app instead of target version. So in your case you should use iOS 7.

You may find out how to download older version of iOS simulator (7.x in your case) by 
[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032635/510577).